# sending object to axis 2 web service

Tags: apache-axis, axis

I m trying to create a java web service using Axis 2, that gets a custom MyClass object as a parameter.
In example :

```
public MyService{
    public String serviceMethod(MyClass myObject){
        return myObject.getUsername();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to send a MyClass object to service and get response?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Just use the POJO approach and Axis2 handles this for you. I'm not sure if you have tried it yet or are just asking?

Comment: Hello ronnie, problem solved many days ago but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Feel free to answer your won question here then, helps others! :)